# Blade template - Display data type message

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I try to display a post from my database. The entry look like this in the database

```
         +"mail_id": "2e8e76a7-3484-412d-ac81-e54d1a1326d8",
         +"city_id": "aa2ccd4b-ceac-476c-b8e2-4294a5e00918",
         +"sender_id": "1a6a13f9-32d5-4f67-8d73-c7bfbedfdde8",
         +"mail_title": "This is a strong test",
         +"mail_message": """
           Strong testing\r\n
           \r\n
           clip\r\n
           \r\n
           Test\r\n
           \r\n
           ALLOOO\r\n
           \r\n
           -PS 33333
           """,
         +"mail_icon": "",
         +"mail_color": "",
         +"mail_read": 0,
         +"created_at": "2019-12-10 16:13:52",
         +"updated_at": "2019-12-10 16:13:52",
       },
```

When i display this in my blade template, it doesn't take the \r and the \n so all my text is on the same line

```
{!! $mail->first()->mail_message !!}
```

i also tried

```
{!! html_entity_decode($mail->first()->mail_message) !!}
```

Nothing work i always get the message on the same line in my display

Comment: How about `{!! nl2br($mail->first()->mail_message) !!}`? That should convert `\n` into `<br/>`, which should be handled by `{!! ... !!}`

Comment: i guess you could put what you have inside `<pre> ... </pre>` also

Comment: This is now solved with the nl2br thing and the <pre> work too !! thanks a lot guys